# How do i disable the in-app settings button

Tags: java, android, settings

I made an app that only has one button and one function. The function is not important. Every app has a settings button at the top right corner (the one with the three dots). My app has no need for settings so how do i disable this settings button, or just take away the ability to click on it? (ive been googling a lot and its hard to find something in my opinion)

Comment: I'm guessing you added your Activity from the context menu in the package manager? This adds an options menu by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's appearing because you're adding an options menu..

Remove the code in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_name, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Also remember to remove the associated XML file to keep the codebase clean.

Comment: ooooh wow turns out i have absolutely no idea what im doing. Thanks it worked!

Comment: i have to wait 7minutes to accept it as the correct answer sorry!

Comment: Ok - I should have answered slower ;)